# Remove additional file after install opencv on raspberry pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I installed OpenCV 3 and got 4GB of my memory space. After build, how can I remove extra files and just stay OpenCV?

According to this article:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43119824/7727838)

Comment: If you're going to use opencv with Python, the easiest way to install opencv on a Raspberry Pi is: `pip3 install opencv-python` and `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`. Using these commands, you'll not need to download additional or unnecessary files. It is to be noticed that this method works only on Raspbian Stretch and above and Python 3 ( This method does not work with Raspbian Jessy and Python 2)

Comment: @singrium What version of OpenCV is installed with this method? 2 or 3?

Comment: If you don't specify the version by yourself, it will download the latest version which is 3.4.2, but if you want a specific version: run this `pip3 install opencv-python == <version number>` and `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python == <version number>`

Comment: @singrium i try this method but give me an error: """ImportError: libcblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"""

Comment: Did this error occur when you tried the commands above or when you did `import cv2` ?
Opencv have some dependencies that you should install first: run these commands to install the needed packages, then install Opencv
`sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev`
`sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev`
`sudo apt-get install libqtgui4`
`sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`